# Seleccionar fila de una gridview sin botones, checkbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, gridview

Hola tengo la siguiente gridview que se carga apartir de un select, con unos campos en blanco, queria saber si hay alguna manera de que cuando se seleccione un registro de dicha tabla me cargue los datos correspondientes en los textbox? por alguna razon el evento select index change no funciona y los ejemplos que en encuentro en internet implica crear una columna que tenga algun boton para seleccionar la fila

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Esto es posible con el evento **CellMouseClick o CellMouseDobleClick**, dependiendo lo que más te convenga. Un ejemplo de cómo usarlo es el siguiente.

```
private void dtg_Marca_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
            int filaSeleccionada = e.RowIndex;
            marBO = new Cls_MarcaBO();

            /*agrega valores a un objeto de la clase BO mediante la fila
            seleccionada y el nombre o número de la columna de la columna*/

            //se selecciona el id para mostrar los datos en los txt

            //Ejemplo columna por número
            marBO.Id_marca = int.Parse(dtg_Marca.Rows[filaSeleccionada].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

            //Ejemplo columna por nombre
            marBO.Marca = dtg_Marca.Rows[filaSeleccionada].Cells["nombre_marca"].Value.ToString();

            //Poner valores en txt
            txt_ClaMar.Text = marBO.Id_marca.ToString();
            txt_NomMar.Text = marBO.Marca;

            //Activar/Desactivar botones en caso de requerirlo.
            btn_NuevoMar.Enabled = true;
            btn_EliminarMar.Enabled = true;
            btn_ActualizarMar.Enabled = true;
            btn_GuardarMar.Enabled = false;
            txt_NomMar.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: gracias, lo voy intentar

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue de utilidad considera votar y aceptarla.

Answer (score -3):

Tengo este método y así parece que funciona.

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gwCodigos" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gwCodigos_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

.cs

```
protected void gwCodigos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTipoActividad.Text = gwCodigos.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        ddlCIIUPrimario.SelectedItem.Text = gwCodigos.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    }
```

Comment: asp? No pone asp por ninguna parte en la pregunta

Comment: Pero es muy similar y en algo lo puede orientar

Comment: Hola Vulpex. Las respuestas por muy simples que sean han de ir explicadas. No todo el mundo entiende igual. Respecto a tu respuesta, gracias por aportar y querer de ayudar pero la respuesta tiene que estar relacionada con el problema del que pregunta, siguiendo la misma tecnología. Mira [answer] para más info.